# Error trying to run phan 2.x because of php-ast

Tags: php

I can't find the solution about "ERROR: Phan 2.x requires php-ast 1.0.1+ because it depends on AST version 70. php-ast 0.1.6 is installed."

```
root@desk:/mnt/d/ibr/phan$ ./phan
ERROR: Phan 2.x requires php-ast 1.0.1+ because it depends on AST version 70. php-ast 0.1.6 is installed.
Exiting without analyzing files.
```

Comment: It exactly tells you the issue you're having. Update your php-ast and read [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The AST version that comes in the official PHP repository is too old to work with phan. You have 2 options here:

1. Run phan with `--allow-polyfill-parser parameter`, which is significantly slower, but works without installing the extension.
2. Install ast from pecl.

   For Ubuntu 18.04 I had to do:

   ```
   sudo apt install php7.2-dev php-pear
   sudo pecl install ast`
   sudo phpenmod ast
   ```

   For non-Debian based distros, you need to install `phpize` and `pecl`, run `pecl install ast` as root and then edit php.ini to add `extension=ast.so`